# Is there a SSE2 equivalent for _mm_insert_epi32?

Tags: sse

I'm porting some code, which makes heavy use of SSE4-intrinsics. It has a non-SSE implementation, but I'd like CPUs with only SSE2 to still be able to use the faster functions.

Could someone suggest an efficient replacement for `_mm_insert_epi32` -- I think, I got everything else covered already... In fact, the second and the third arguments of the function are zeros in my case:

```
foo = _mm_insert_epi32(vec, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

So you actually want to zero the low element of a vector?  That's a bad use-case for `_mm_insert_epi32`.  It's 2 uops on Intel CPUs, one of them requiring the shuffle port.

In both your SSE4.1 and SSE2 versions, use

```
foo = _mm_and_si128(vec, _mm_set_epi32(-1,-1,-1, 0));   // mask off the low element
```

---

Alternatively, use `movss` from a zeroed vector, but this might cause a bypass delay for using an FP shuffle between two integer instructions.  There's an annoying amount of casting in the C intrinsics version, so it's easier read as asm.

```
# vec in xmm0
pxor   xmm1, xmm1    ; _mm_setzero_si128()
movss  xmm0, xmm1    ; zero the low 32 bits of xmm0
```

---

2x `_mm_insert_epi16` is almost certainly not the best way to do this, even if you wanted to replace an element other than the low element with variable contents.  It's a 2-uop instruction, but for a lot of cases you can get the job done with fewer than 4 uops.

For variable contents, it would probably be better to use [`_mm_cvtsi32_si128` (`movd`)](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVD:MOVQ.html) and shuffle two vectors together.  The unpack instructions are handy for combining data from two registers, and so is `shufps` (yes, you can use it on integer data).

You could also shuffle `vec` so the element to replace is the low element, then replace it with `movss` (or AND/OR).

Maybe 2x `pinsrw` isn't horrible for the general case, but most specific cases should let you come up with something better.  See http://agner.org/optimize/ and the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for more resources to help you write efficient code.